# Substitute variable in a command in Python

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, variables

I'm pretty novice in Python scripting and was trying to run an API call with some dynamic values passed.

A simple idea about the code is, it gets two datetimes in epoch(10 second interval)and calls an API to do a function.

```
import commands
end = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s"))
start = str((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)).strftime("%s"))
output = commands.getstatusoutput("curl 'http://my-api-url/object?param1=1&start=$start&end=$end&function=average'")
```

It doesn't work as the variables `start` and `end` are not getting expanded/substituted.

As you see, I come from bash scripting and tried looking on several variable substitution commands from web, but nothing specific found to my case here.

Comment: Try `"curl 'http://my-api-url/object?param1=1&start={}&end={}&function=average'".format(start, end)`. But you will lose a lot more time trying to advance like this than to look at Python doc.

Comment: Python isn't PHP, it has a C-style string interpolation system (in various versions from almost-C to C-inspired). See [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for how to insert values in strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
import commands
end = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s"))
start = str((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)).strftime("%s"))
output = commands.getstatusoutput("curl 'http://my-api-url/object?param1=1&start={start}&end={end}&function=average'".format(start=start, end=end))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can concatenate strings using the '+' operator.
In your case you could write:

```
output = commands.getstatusoutput("curl 'http://my-api-url/object?param1=1&start=" + start + "&end=" + end + "&function=average'")
```